# How to Clear UITextfield Text and Ok button in UIAlertView in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Created Password Validation. Password created successfully it will show one `UIAlertView` and press when user presses the OK, the Password Text field will get clear. How to do that? Please any Example?

Answer (score 0):

Add `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Show Alert View using :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE_HERE" 
                                                message:@"ALERT_MESSAGE HERE." 
                                                delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

After user presses OK,  this method will called automatically:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked OK
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // do something here...
        yourTextField.text = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you want the password field text to be empty after displaying the UIAlert, please add the following code to make your password filed empty.

```
yourTextField.text = ""
```

Here's an example.

```
if(passwordValid==YES)
{
UIAlertView *passwordValidated = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Validated!"
                                                                                          message:@"Your password is successfully validated. Press OK to continue"
                                                                                         delegate:nil
                                                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

yourTextField.text = "";


[updateMessage show];
```